# Using radio buttons and link_to with Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, radio-button

Bit of a Rails newbie here so please bear with me.

I am trying to list a bunch of entries in a table by first listing a radio button for each entry, and then the fields for the entry as just text.

It's working fine, it's displaying the way I want it too. However, the problem is whenever I'm using my buttons. The idea is to have the user select one of the radio buttons to choose a specific recipe, and then click on one of the universal Add, Edit, Delete buttons at the top of the page to perform the respective action on the selected recipe.

So far this is my code:

```
<!--Action buttons at the top of page, supposed to communicate with the radio buttons --> 
<%= link_to("Show", {:action => 'show', :id => recipe.id}, :class => 'action show') %>
<%= link_to("Edit", {:action => 'edit', :id => recipe.id}, :class => 'action edit') %>
<%= link_to("Delete", {:action => 'delete', :id => recipe.id}, :class => 'action delete') %> 

<% @recipes.each do |recipe| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= radio_button_tag 'recipe', recipe, @recipe == recipe %></td>
  <td><%= recipe.total_calories %></td>
  <td><%=........15 more fields
</tr>`
<% end unless @recipes.nil? %>
```

It's throwing me an error that undefined local variable or method `recipe'. I get why I'm getting the error; Ruby doesn't know exactly which recipe the user is selecting via the radio button. Can someone show me how to get the radio buttons to communicate with the action button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way of doing this would be to create a form containing the actions as submission button values. Something like:

```
<%= form_tag(PATH_TO_YOUR_CONTROLLER) do %>
   <%= submit_tag("Show") %>
   <%= submit_tag("Edit") %>
   <%= submit_tag("Delete") %>

   RECIPE_LIST_HERE
<% end >
```

Then your controller would need to look up what action and recipe were submitted (I believe those will be under params[:commit] and params[:recipe]).

Comment: Is there any ways I can do it with link_to's? Or is it too complicated and time-consuming?

Comment: You could add an onClick javascript handler to your link_to to set a hidden form field containing the action, and submit the form. But if your goal is just to have your buttons look like links, you could use CSS.

Comment: For some reason, every time I try to access params[:recipe] in my controller via "variableName = params[:recipe]" and try to log the variable, it keeps coming out as nil. Am I doing it right?

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's under another key. If you log `params.inspect`, does it show *anything* related to the selected recipe?

Comment: It does log some sort of memory value for recipe. However, it doesn't return an actual recipe object with the selected recipe's field data and unique id, which is what I want.

Comment: Should I be using a form_for instead?

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. Try doing `radio_button_tag 'recipe', recipe.id, @recipe == recipe`, and then doing a `recipe = Recipe.find(params[:recipe])` in your controller. Unfortunately form_for won't work because you don't know in advance which recipe the form should be built around.

Comment: Actually I managed to solve it with a form for! I used this  `<%= form_for( :parameter, :url => { :action => 'chooseOption'} ) do |f| %>` and in the controller, I did `@recipe = Recipe.find( [:parameters][:recipe])`. Is this good practice?

Comment: Sure, that works well, I didn't realize recipes were "scoped" by something.